# new Date as react key prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this react code where i am using new Date().getTime() as react key props on some Input components.This is probably an antipattern because keys need to be stable. But i want to understand why is this so buggy. And why newDate().getTime() as key behaves worse than Math.random() as key.Please check these 2 examples out to see what i mean:

- [example with Math.random() as key](https://codepen.io/shadyPillgrim/pen/gjRENE)
- [example with new Date().getTime() as key](https://codepen.io/shadyPillgrim/pen/GBEbLP)

**The kind of code in question:**

```
class TextInputs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    textArray: ['hi,','My','Name','is']
  };
  handleChange = ({value, index}) => {
    const {textArray} = this.state;
    textArray[index] = value;
    this.setState({textArray})
  };
  render(){
    console.log(this.state.textArray)
  return this.state.textArray.map((txt, i) => <Input onChange={this.handleChange} index={i} value={txt} key={new Date().getTime()}/>)               
  };
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This is probably an antipattern because keys need to be stable.

Indeed. :-)

> But i want to understand why is this so buggy. And why newDate().getTime() as key behaves worse than Math.random() as key.

Because you can render **lots** of elements within the same millisecond. A millisecond is a very short time to humans. To computers, not so much. So you end up with keys that aren't unique.

Before you (or anyone reading this) is tempted to reach for [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) instead, remember that as you said, keys need to be stable, and also `performance.now()`'s accuracy opened the door to some attacks and so implementations have backed off (it's still really precise, but not accurate to the 5 microseconds it was originally supposed to be).

---

Side note: This code is wrong:

```
handleChange = ({value, index}) => {
  const {textArray} = this.state;
  textArray[index] = value;
  this.setState({textArray})
};
```

There are two problems with that code, both described on [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) in the documentation:

1. You're modifying state directly, when assigning to the array entry. You must **copy** the array and modify the copy.
2. You're using the non-callback version of `setState` to set state based on existing state. When setting state based on existing state, you **must** use the callback version of `setState`.

Ideally, don't use array indexes for this at all; use a unique ID on the object. But if you use an index, the correct code would be:

```
handleChange = ({value, index}) => {
  // Remember the string we're supposed to remove
  const entry = this.state.textArray[index];
  this.setState(({textArray}) => { // <== Note destructuring
      // Find the first occurrence in the array as it is NOW (it may have changed)
      const index = textArray.indexOf(entry);
      // If the entry is still there...
      if (index != -1) {
          // ...create a copy of the array without it, return the state update
          return {textArray: textArray.filter((e, i) => i !== index)};
          // Or:
          // textArray = textArray.slice();
          // textArray.splice(index, 1);
          // return {textArray};
          // Or:
          // return {textArray: [...textArray.slice(0, index), ...textArray.slice(index + 1)]};
      }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. performance.now() was completely new to me.But why are there like so inputs in the dom after i type into them even though i am mapping only 3?

Comment: @ShadyPillgrim - The keys are neither stable nor unique. It's not surprising that React doesn't do what you want it to do when you violate both constraints it puts on keys. :-)

Comment: @ShadyPillgrim - I've added a side note to the answer, the `handleChange` code has two state management issues I thought I'd flag up.

Comment: @iLuvLogix - Doh! Yes indeed. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You're changing the key every time that renders, defeating the purpose of keys in react.  The key is meant to allow React to keep track of the diffs in components so it know what/when to re-render.  In this case, if you don't have a natural key it's best using `i`

Keys need to be consistent.  Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 3):

The reason your app is behaving weirdly is that keys are not unique. The resolution of the `new Date().getTime()` is millisecond. When you do that in the loop it's faster than a single millisecond so some of the items get the same key.

Try running `for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { console.log((new Date).getTime()) }` in the browser's console and see the result.

Comment: Wow. a  lot of the logs are of the same time stamp  and they are only a millisecond apart . Is this happening because the loop is ending under a millisecond?

Comment: Every millisecond the loop make few turnarounds. This is why some of the keys are duplicated in the table.

Comment: Are u suggesting that some of the keys will be same?  and not unique.But why are there  so inputs in the dom after i type int them even though am mapping only 4 and the length has not changed?