# this.setState isn't working (my state is a number)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I am having a problem with: this.setState({score: counter}); For some reason it's not updating. Why? Even when I do this.setState({score: 5}) or score:"a string" it still doesn't work. Am I missing something? Whatever I do, the state won't change. I have to add extra description because the website won't let me post my question.

```
displayResultsHandler = () => {
    var counter = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.correctAnswers.length; i++) {
      if(this.state.correctAnswers[i] === this.state.userAnswers[i]) {
        counter = counter+1;
      }
    }

this.setState({
  score: counter
});

console.log("counter: " + counter);
console.log("score: " + this.state.score); // For some reason, this is always zero
```

}

I added my full code below. Maybe it will help.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Title from './Title/Title';
import Question from './Question/Question';
import Aux from './hoc/Aux';
import SubmitButton from './SubmitButton/SubmitButton';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    questionArray: [
      "What is 9+10",
      "How many goals did Ronaldo score against Spain in the World Cup 2018",
      "Who Stole Ronaldo's (CR7) greates ever goal?",
      "Which one of these players ruined the NBA",
      "Who is currently number 1 in the internet L rankings?"
  ],
    answerChoicesArray: [
      ["1", "19", "21", "90", "-1"],
      ["1", "3", "5", "0", "-1"],
      ["Pepe", "Messi", "Casillas", "Benzema", "Nani"],
      ["Allen Iverson", "Kevin Durant", "Steph Curry", "Lebron James", "Russel Westbrook"],
      ["Drake", "Pusha T", "Russel Westbrook", "Lil Xan", "Russ"]
    ],

    correctAnswers: ["21", "3", "Nani", "Kevin Durant", "Russ"],

    userAnswers: ["", "", "", "", ""],

    score: 0

  }

  updateUserAnswersHandler = (oldArray, index, value) => {
    const newArray = oldArray;
    newArray[index] = value;
    this.setState({
      userAnswers: newArray
    });
  }

  displayResultsHandler = () => {
    var counter = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.correctAnswers.length; i++) {
      if(this.state.correctAnswers[i] === this.state.userAnswers[i]) {
        counter = counter+1;
      }
    }

    this.setState({
      score: counter
    });

    console.log("counter: " + counter);
    console.log("score: " + this.state.score); // For some reason, this is always zero

    if(this.state.score < 5) {
      alert("You're dumb asf. Please leave");
    } else {
      alert("Welcome to NASA");
    }
  }

  render() {
    // var userAnswers;
    // console.log(userAnswers); How do I pass this as a prop? this.userAnswers? nope. Therefore it has to be a state
    console.log("User Answers are: " + this.state.userAnswers);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          
            <Title/>
            <h2>Only the most genius of individuals will pass</h2>
            <hr/>
            <Question
              correctAnswers={this.state.correctAnswers}
              updateUserAnswersHandler={this.updateUserAnswersHandler}
              userAnswers={this.state.userAnswers}
              questionArray={this.state.questionArray}
              answerChoicesArray={this.state.answerChoicesArray} />
            <SubmitButton
              clicked = {this.displayResultsHandler} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you added constructor in class ?

Comment: No. I thought we didn't need constructors in the newest version? Because I was able to change my userAnswers state without a constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

State updates are **asynchronous**. Your call to `setState` just queues the update, it doesn't make it happen immediately.

You're also using the wrong overload of `setState` (you're not alone, lots of people do!). When you're setting new state based on existing state, you **cannot** use the version that just accepts an object. You must use the callback version. If you want to use the resulting state when you're done, you can pass a second function which will be called  when the state update is complete:

```
displayResultsHandler = () => {
    this.setState(
        // Updater
        prevState => {
            var counter = 0;
            for(let i = 0; i < prevState.correctAnswers.length; i++) {
              if(prevState.correctAnswers[i] === prevState.userAnswers[i]) {
                counter = counter+1;
              }
            }
            return {score: counter};
        },
        // Completion callback
        () => {
            console.log("score: " + this.state.score);
        }
    );
};
```

However, the documentation says this about using the completion callback:

> Generally we recommend using `componentDidUpdate()` for such logic instead.

This is all covered on [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) of the documentation, and in the [`setState` API docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

---

Just as a side note, a couple of advanced JavaScript features (destructuring and shorthand property notation) and a prosaic one (increment operator) can make that code a bit more concise:

```
displayResultsHandler = () => {
    this.setState(
        // Updater
        ({correctAnswers, userAnswers}) => {                  // *** Destructuring
            let score = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++) {
              if (correctAnswers[i] === userAnswers[i]) {
                ++score;                                      // *** Increment
              }
            }
            return {score};                                   // *** Shorthand property
        },
        // Completion callback
        () => {
            console.log("score: " + this.state.score);
        }
    );
};
```

Some people might even use `reduce` instead of that `for` loop; I'm not convinced readability isn't impacted, though:

```
displayResultsHandler = () => {
    this.setState(
        // Updater
        ({correctAnswers, userAnswers}) => ({
            score: correctAnswers.reduce(
                (score, answer, index) =>
                    score + (answer === userAnswers[index] ? 1 : 0),
                0
            )
        }),
        // Completion callback
        () => {
            console.log("score: " + this.state.score);
        }
    );
};
```

(You could even drop the conditional operator and just use `score + (answer === userAnswers[index])` since `true` coerces to `1` and `false` coerces to `0`, but...)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you !

Comment: So I get what you're saying. But I didn't use setState based on the existing state. I did setState({score: counter}), how is that based on the existing state? Would I also need to update this handler for modifying userAnswers array?

  updateUserAnswersHandler = (oldArray, index, value) => {
    const newArray = oldArray;
    newArray[index] = value;
    this.setState({
      userAnswers: newArray
    });
  }

Comment: *"I did setState({score: counter}), how is that based on the existing state?"* Where did that `counter` value come from? :-) Yes, that other handler also needs to be fixed, more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51524337/157247

Comment: @user7552492 - Looking again, the answer to your question about the `updateUserAnswersHandler` handler depends on where `oldArray` comes from. But yes, it probably has the same problem.

Comment: Yeah. If you look at the longer piece of code I sent, I passed my userAnswers state twice as a prop to my Question component like this: **userAnswers={this.state.userAnswers}**. And two files down, I called the updateUsersHandler like this: **this.props.updateUserAnswersHandler(this.props.userAnswers, this.props.index, individualAnswer);**. I'm pretty sure I have to fix this because it's using an old state (this.props.userAnswers) but I'm not sure how to.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this.setState is an asynchronous function.

try this -

```
this.setState({
  score: counter
},function(){
  console.log(this.state.score)
})
```

Comment: No, the OP must use the updater callback, not pass in an object directly, because this is a state update based on state.

Comment: That method prints the correct state, but the state itself is still zero